# Getting time duration between list of dates in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file with long list of start dates and end dates in the format `YYYYMMDD` i.e. 20170516, 20170430 ..
I have to find the duration between `start_date` and `sell_date` which are in the format of string initially.
I have to add column of the duration of days between these dates. Following is what I have tried.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

data = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')

data['start_date'] = map(lambda t:datetime.strptime(t,'%Y%M%d'), data.start_date.values)
data['sell_date'] = map(lambda t:datetime.strptime(t,'%Y%M%d'), data.sell_date.values)
data['duration'] = data.sell_date.values - data.start_date.values
```

But this gives the following error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'map' and 'map'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is actually very hard and interesting. It require complex computing so sorry. no api or library is available. And however using image to complete this task is very difficult. You should use another approach like distance sensor, etc

If you really really want to use image to complete this task. 
In my opinion, i should be implemented as follow

```
1. Make a method to calculate real distance (in metrics) from image
2. Take sequence of images, at least 30fps
3. for each image detect the car
   if it is exist go to 4
   if it is not exist, repeat 3
4. calculate the distance
```

Hope that can help you